# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'user.id'. Either include it or remove the dependency array react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Tags: reactjs

How I Fetch All Data Using User Id.

Reactjs Code.

```
 let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user-info"));

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      
      let result = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/getFolder?id="+user.id);
      
      result = await result.json();
      setFile(result);
    }
    fetchData();
  },[]);
  console.warn(file);
```

I run this code but its show me this error

Line 16:5:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'user.id'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Note API Is Working.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to use the user.id only once, it's better to put it inside the useEffect hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user-info"));
      let result = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/getFolder?id="+user.id);
      
      result = await result.json();
      setUserState(user) //if you decide to create an user state
      setFile(result);
    }
    fetchData();
  },[]);
```

Since it's from localStorage, even if you intend to use it in other parts of the component, you can create a state and setState inside the same useEffect hook.

Answer (score 0):

So, in useEffect usually throws a warning when you're using any variable or calling a method in useEffect which you haven't added to your dependency list and the reference exists outside useEfffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
  ...using some variable which isn't in this scope
 }, [..this is dependency list])
```

Dependency list means a group of variable or references which on change can trigger useEffect so it is usually advisable to add those references (variables) in your dependency list which you're using in useEffect so it can be triggered whenever you update them.

So, in your code, you can add user variable inside your useEffect like

```
    let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user-info"));

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user-info"));
      if(!user) return;
      let result = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/getFolder?id="+user.id);
      
      result = await result.json();
      setFile(result);
    }
    fetchData();
  },[]);
  console.warn(file);
```

Cause you want useEffect to get triggered once I suppose.

References:

- https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html